# Does Julia reflection offer introspection and intercession?

Tags: reflection, julia, introspection

I have been looking at Julia documentation on reflection and metaprogramming. It covers introspection broadly (ability to check datatype fields, methods in generic functions, expanding macros and lowering functions) but I have not seen any point where it talks about intercession (ability to change its structure e.g. edit data fields). Does it mean that Julia does not support intercession?

Comment: Are you looking for macros? https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros-1

Comment: Could you define the term "intercession" better? You seem to be using it in a very specific sense, which might not be familiar to all.

Comment: important concepts: 1. Introspection -ability to inspect behavior 2. Intercession- ability to change program's behavior.  For example, the java.lang.reflect API allows you to access\inspect class and object elements (introspection) but it does not allow you to change their contents (does not permit intercession).

Answer (score 1):

Julia's struct is immutable by default, so a struct cannot change fields or values. A mutable struct can have the values of its fields changed but fields cannot be added or deleted. Methods using the struct can be added but generally cannot be removed once added to a given scope.

So a struct in julia supports only a small part of what you call "intercession."

If actually needed, a Julia struct can take a Dict field which can mimic full "intercession" with name-value pairs, at the price of efficiency of access.